# json schema validation using patternProprties with tv4

Tags: node.js, json, support-v4, tv4

I have a json like:

```
{"post": {"someKey": {"anotherKey":"anotherValue"}}}
```

and where the first key is a valid http method and can be either of - post, get etc all valid http method at runtime.

Here is my schema

```
var schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-z]+$": {
            'properties': {
              "type": "object",
              'properties': {
                'someKey':{
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': {
                      'anotherKey': {'type': 'string'},
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
   }
}

var valid = { "post": {"mkey":"myvalue"}}; //This is getting passed but I know that is wrong
var invalid = { "1": {"mkey":"myvalue"}}; //This is passed but actually it should fail

console.log(tv4.validateMultiple(invalid, schema));
```

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out:

```
{
    'type': 'object',
    'patternProperties': {
        '^(POST|GET|DELETE|HEAD|PATCH|HEAD|PUT)$': {
            'additionalProperties': false,
            'type': 'object',
            'required': ['someKey'],
            'properties': {
                'someKey': {
                    'type': 'string'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, things to note:
1.'additionalProperties': false is important  for patternProperties
2. As per JSON Schema spec, you cannot have a case insensitive match and hence all are in upper case